# Trying to use FlexGlobals to access ArrayCollection?

Tags: android, apache-flex

I am currently trying to use the new approach of using FlexGlobals to access an ArrayCollection that I have on the Default view of a mobile application I am developing. Below is the code that makes up the creation and population of that array on the Default view which happens as soon as the app is initiated:

```
private var ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function loop():void
            {
                var index:int;
                for( index = 0; index < compsCollection.length; index++ )
                {
                    trace( "Element " + index + " is " + compsCollection[index].comp_id );
                    trace( ids.length);
                    ids.addItem(compsCollection[index].comp_id);                    
                }               
            }
```

Now when this code is run i can clearly see from the console that the "ids" ArrayCollection is being populated correctly. Now on a different view within the app I want to access this data and use it for various things. I have used the code below to try and access the data for the ArrayCollection:

```
protected var ids_list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {               
                var obj:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters;    
                ids_list.source = obj.ids;              
                trace(ids_list.length);                  
            }
```

When i tried this i do not get an error however the Trace statement returns "0". So I also tried:

```
protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {               
                ids_list.source = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.ids;               
                trace(ids_list.length);                  
            }
```

Which again returned "0" in the trace statement. I finally tried this to see if it would work:

```
protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {               
                ids_list.source = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.ids;              
                trace(ids_list.length);                  
            }
```

When I tried this and navigated to the view where this code would be initated I got this error:

```
Error #1069: Property ids not found on Main and there is no default value.
```

I could only assume that the ArrayCollection I had created in my default view has no value once I navigate away from it. Is there anyway anyone can please help me with this as there seems to be next to no documentation on how to do these types of things with FlexGlobals? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't access a private property, try it

```
/*
Replace

private var ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

by
*/

private var _ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
public set ids(value:ArrayCollection):void{
_ids = value;
}

public get ids():ArrayCollection{
return _ids 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely bad practice for a child component to know anything at all about the structure of its parent/ancestor.  That being said, the reason you can't see the value of the Application's member variable is because you've made it private.  If you want it to be visible outside its own scope, you need to make it public.

Comment: For more on why to avoid global state, check out http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ArrayCollection as a property to your view from the main application.